# Secure Password Programming with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography, md5

I want to convert a Secure Password in secure hashcode. best method?

like: SHA1,MD5 and any combination ?

```
string str ="Krishna";

Output:"!#$!$ASDFAS@#$%@";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to create a random piece of data that can be used for salting. The most common ones are:

- Creating a random GUID by using the `Guid` type
- Creating a random string of digits by using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class

To create a new random GUID, we invoke the `NewGuid` method on the `Guid` type. Once generated, we simply append the salt to the string to be encrypted.

```
string saltAsString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

For creating a random string of digits by using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class, we first initialize a provider and a `byte` array, and then invoke the `GetBytes` method on our provider instance.

```
byte[] saltInBytes = new byte[8];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider saltGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
saltGenerator.GetBytes(saltInBytes);
string saltAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(saltInBytes);
```

The following code is a modified version of the previous snippet to demonstrate salting.

```
public void HashText()
{
    string textToHash = "password"; 
    string saltAsString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    byte[] byteRepresentation 
        = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToHash + saltAsString);

    byte[] hashedTextInBytes = null; 
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider myMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    hashedTextInBytes = myMD5.ComputeHash(byteRepresentation); 
    string hashedText = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedTextInBytes); 

    // will display X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==
    MessageBox.Show(hashedText);
}
```

Comment: A much better idea would be to use a built-in key derivation primitive like PBKDF2, rather than inventing your own.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the default Membership Provider does:

```
 internal string EncodePassword(string pass)
    {
        string salt = GenerateSalt();

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
        HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }

    internal string GenerateSalt()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buff = new byte[32];
        rng.GetBytes(buff);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string Cipher(object obj)
{
    string j = JSON(obj);
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("salt");
        aesAlg.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("salt");
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(j);
                }
                byte[] encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted).Replace('/', '-').Replace('+', '_').Replace("=", "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using something like [BCrypt](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) instead of SHA1. Using SHA1 is not a great way to store passwords as it is very vulnerable to dictionary attacks, even with a salt. SHA1 is a fast algorithm and is designed to work against large amounts of data, fast. It is possible to calculate [millions of hashes per second](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) on even older computers.

BCrypt uses a modified encryption algorithm along with a salt which makes it expensive to calculate a single hash by using something called a *work factor*. It takes advantage of the fact that the attackers will need to calculate many hashes, while for legitimate verification you only need to calculate one.

Also read the excellent article, [How to Safely Store a Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) for a more in depth explanation.